# Разговор discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Как в боте discord.py сделать, чтобы бот отвечал на слова без префикса?

Comment: Ну погугли что-ли, вот уже нашел ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956326/how-do-i-set-a-in-discord-py-a-command-without-prefix-only-with-certain-word-to

Answer (score 2):

```
from typing import List

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

client = commands.Bot( command_prefix= "*" )

# Words
hello_words = [ 'твой текст','твой текст', 'твой текст' ]
@client.event

async def on_ready ():
       print( 'BOT connected ' )

@client.event

async def on_message( message ):
    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send( 'Твой текст' )

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send ( 'Твой текст' )

    if msg in hello_words:
        await message.channel.send ( 'Твой тект' )
client.run('Твой токен')
```

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей в ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, что вы хотите сделать что-то похожее на это.

```py
## Перед кодом можем сделать вот такой список
## Перед кодом можем сделать вот такой список
words = ['привет, бот!']

## Далее уже код команды... а если быть точнее, ивента.
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 cnt = message.content.lower() ## определяем нижний регистр, т.е.: "привет, бот"
 if cnt in words:
  await message.channel.send(f'Привет, привет, {message.author.mention}!')
```

А также можно сделать вариант с рандомными ответами. Это так-же можно через `answer = ['ответ1', 'ответ2']` и `await message.channel.send(f'{random.choice(answer)}')`.

Надеюсь, я вам помог.

Answer (score 0):

самый лёгкий вариант:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "Всем привет":
        await message.channel.send(f"Приветствую!")
    if message.content == "Как дела?":
        await message.channel.send(f"у меня хорошо")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```